# How to create own dataprovider for each DataGrid column?

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, arraycollection, dataprovider

There are several ArrayCollections and DataGrid in my application. Number of ArrayCollections determined by the input data. How to create own dataprovider for each DataGrid column?

Answer (score 1):

Good starting point would be to inherit DataGrid and override function set dataProvider. Then you have to implement all logic that is responsible for dealing with your data structure. But it won't be easy without deep knowlege of Flex.

Instead I would suggest you to create some sort of util that will merge your data into the format that DataGrid accepts.

Comment: Thank you. I don't deep knowledge of Flex. I thought to create a utility, that will merge my data into the format that DataGrid accepts. But even here I have not found a solution. 
I have an XML-document from which I am reading the data. If it contains 10 elements, I created 10 ArrayCollections and put them into an array. With the data in ArrayCollections I do a lot of computing operations. Therefore, store them in an ArrayCollection is very comfortable for me. What data structure would be most convenient for this situation? May be XML? I would like to find a productive solution.

Comment: In case you get a reply for the server, consider to adjust your server code that it returns one XML. XML is a great thing to works with in Flex. Think how you can simplify your code. For me it seems that you have pretty simple task but you use most complicated approach. p.s. If you need further help - provide more details :-) All the best, Max

Comment: Thank you, MinimeDJ. I did it by using XML.